# quickSort array of structures: incorrect sort

Tags: c, quicksort, structure

I'm having a problem with the following VS 2010 code.  Am trying to sort an array of structures.  The code compiles without errors, is very fast, but has a problem in that the sort result is incorrect.

I am sorting by the "zip" character string (for test purposes, NOT numerically, but by character compare).  I have a version of this running using the standard lib qsort, but want to do some further fiddling so am writing my own.

```
 struct address {

  char name[40];
  char street[40];
  char city[20];
  char state[30];
  char zip[21];
};


void qs_struct(struct address items[], int left, int right)
{

  int i, j;
  char *x;
  struct address temp;

  i = left; 
  j = right;
  x = items[(left+right)/2].zip;

  do {
      while((strcmp(items[i].zip,x) < 0) && (i < right)){ i++;}
      while((strcmp(items[j].zip,x) > 0) && (j > left)) { j--;}

    if(i <= j) {
      temp = items[i];
      items[i] = items[j];
      items[j] = temp;
      i++; j--;
    }
  } while(i <= j);

  if(left < j) qs_struct(items, left, j);
  if(i < right) qs_struct(items, i, right);
}


void qx(struct address items[], int count)
{
  qs_struct(items,0,count-1);
}

void fillStructWithRandomDataForTest(struct address *addr, int i, int j)
{
    char temp[444];


            sprintf(temp, "%d%d", j +i, j*i);
            strcpy(addr->name, temp);
            sprintf(temp, "%d%d", j +i, j*i);
            strcpy(addr->street, temp);

            sprintf(temp, "%d%d", j +i, j*i);
            strcpy(addr->city, temp);
            sprintf(temp, "%d%d", j +i, j*i);
            strcpy(addr->state, temp);

            sprintf(temp, "%d%d", j +i, j*i);
            strcpy(addr->zip, temp);

}

 void xqs(void)
  {
  struct address addrs[20];

   for (int i = 0, j = 33; i < 16; ++i, --j)
        fillStructWithRandomDataForTest(&addrs[i], i, j);

    qx(addrs, 16);

    // results: incorrectly sorted
    for (int k = 0; k < 16; ++k)
        printf("%s \n",addrs[k].zip);

 }
```

Comment: Actually, there's a built-in `qsort()` function in the C library.

Comment: Yes, I use it all the time.  For various reasons need to roll my own here.

Comment: Does your test code work if you substitute your qsort with the standard library qsort?  And in exactly what way are your results incorrect?

Comment: Yes, works fine with stdlib qsort.  The exact way in which they are incorrect is that the first 5 items are sorted correctly; but then the next group, while sorted correctly in itself, is out of order with respect to the first 5. Simplified erroneous output:  331  3312 3314 3317 [wrong here->] 330 3305 3324  etc

Comment: difficult to see why you can't use std lib qsort

Comment: Here is the exact output: 330 
33116 
33140 
33162 
33182 
33200 
33216 
33230 
3332 
3362 
33242 
33252 
33260 
33266 
33270 
3390

Comment: @DavidHeffernan You have to trust him that he has his own reasons.

Comment: I can use stdlib qsort, but the sort (1.2 million strings) takes over 5 mins on a dual xeon processor machine with 192 gig of ram.  I am going to make the sort parallel (using openMp), so it can run on all 24 logical cores.  My guess is that it will reduce that 5 mins to about 15 seconds.  But I need to get it working first without openMp.

Comment: Let me suggest something to try: instead of while((strcmp(items[i].zip,x) < 0) && (i < right)){ i++;} try while((i < right) && (strcmp(items[i].zip,x) < 0)){ i++;} (and the same for j)

Comment: Write a general sort routine. Don't build your types into it. Abstract and generalise. Easier to check and test also. And use a pre existing openmp quick sort. There are millions out there. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Tried that. Still a problem.  But thanks for trying!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan.  I'm all for !wheel reinvention.  But I spent several hours trying to find an openmp c quick sort...where are they?

Comment: Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163717.aspx

Comment: Your fundamental problem is that you have not written a general sort algo. Write something that has the same sig as stdlib qsort and that can sort anything. Then test on integers. Then build it up. But I cannot stress enough, do not put specific types in the middle of your qsort!

Comment: I completely agree with all of your programming advice, and I would never put specific types in the middle of a qsort.  The code you are seeing is only my attempt to simplify and isolate the problem for presentation here. btw, that link I had already seen.  It illustrates how to add openmp to extant quicksort code, but it doesn't have any quicksort code.  (I already know how to add the openmp stuff...what I need is the quicksort source code for sorting an array of structures.)

Comment: Oh so this is not even the real code? Does your sort work with integer arrays?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  If you have any constructive comments as to the errors in the code in original post, please say so.  Otherwise, please refrain.

Comment: If you cannot see constructive comments here then I guess I cannot help you

Comment: Try using the version here: http://cprogramminglanguage.net/quicksort-algorithm-c-source-code.aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan   The link to that version enabled me to identify the problem: So how do I put a check mark next to your name as the one who solved the problem which was: Instead of this:
    while((i < n) && (strcmp(list[i].name, key) < 0)) i++;   
          while((j > m) && (strcmp(list[j].name , key) > 0)) j--;
should be this:
    
   while((i <= n) && (strcmp(list[i].name, key) <= 0)) i++;
         while((j >= m) && (strcmp(list[j].name , key) > 0)) j--;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
x = items[(left+right)/2].zip;
```

ties the pivot to a position. When the middle address is moved, the pivot against which the zips are compared is changed. That messes up the sort. You need to copy the zip against which to compare,

```
x = strdup(items[(left+right)/2].zip); // or strlen and malloc
while (...)
free(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice if you had told us in precisely what way your results are incorrect, but it is okay, let me guess: it prints nothing, right? All blank lines, eh?

The very last loop in your code uses `k` as loop counter, but then it uses `i` as an index to select a struct to `printf()`. This will always select `addrs[16]`, which has not been initialized.

You need coffee.  Or sleep.  But not both.

Comment: And then the question was edited to fix this problem, with no further comment about whether it resolved the problem, nor with what the residual problems are if there are still some.

Comment: Oops.  Fixed that.  Unfortunately, that had nothing at all to do with the problem in the code, so in no way whatsoever did the question get answered.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Official further comment: that fix in no way resolved anything with the code.  All problems remain.  I don't drink coffee, and I can't sleep because of this bug.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan LOL David! Very well said!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
 while((i < n) && (strcmp(list[i].name, key) < 0)) i++;


while((j > m) && (strcmp(list[j].name , key) > 0)) j--;
```

should be this:

```
 while((i <= n) && (strcmp(list[i].name, key) <= 0)) i++;
 while((j >= m) && (strcmp(list[j].name , key) > 0)) j--;
```